# Error: 419 | Page Expired in Laravel 9 multiple choice questions

Tags: php, laravel

I currently making an expert system with a multiple choice exam questions system

this is input view

```
<form action="{{ route('diagnosa.submit') }}" method="post">
  @csrf
    <label for="diagnosa1">Asap yang dihasilkan hitam:</label>
    <select id="diagnosa1" name="diagnosa1">
      <option value="true">iya</option>
      <option value="false">tidak</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <label for="diagnosa2">Suara mesin kasar:</label>
    <select id="diagnosa2" name="diagnosa2">
      <option value="true">iya</option>
      <option value="false">tidak</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <label for="diagnosa3">Pembakaran mesin berlebihan:</label>
    <select id="diagnosa3" name="diagnosa3">
      <option value="true">iya</option>
      <option value="false">tidak</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    

    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()" class="edit-button">Edit</button>
    
  </form>
</body>
```

route

```
Route::post('/frontend/sistempakar', [HomeController::class, 'submit'])->name('diagnosa.submit');
```

controller

```
public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        // Your validation logic here
        $hasil = $this->validateDiagnosa($request->all());

        // Return the result view with the diagnosis result
        return view('result')->with('hasil', $hasil);
    }

    private function validateDiagnosa($input)
    {
        // Your validation logic based on the selected values
        // Example logic, adjust as needed
        if ($input['diagnosa1'] == 'true' && $input['diagnosa2'] == 'true' && $input['diagnosa3'] == 'true') {
            return "Ada masalah pada siklus pembakaran";
        } elseif ($input['diagnosa1'] == 'true' && $input['diagnosa2'] == 'false' && $input['diagnosa3'] == 'false') {
            return "Ada masalah pada jalur pembakaran, bisa juga disebabkan oleh jalur yang kotor";
        } elseif ($input['diagnosa1'] == 'false' && $input['diagnosa2'] == 'true' && $input['diagnosa3'] == 'false') {
            return "Masalah pada piston";
        } else {
            return "Tidak dapat membuat diagnosis";
        }
    }
```

my table

| Diagnosa 1 | Diagnosa 2 | Diagnosa 3 | Hasil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | ada masalah pada siklus pembakaran |
| True | Flase | Flase | ada masalah pada jalur pembakaran, bisa juga |
| Fasle | True | Flase | Masalah pada piston |

my problem is that the results are not showing up and only displaying 419 | PAGE EXPIRED

Am I missing something here? or my code has errors?

I hope to find an answer because I am quite new and I am quite frustrated with this

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `419` is the response you get from failed CSRF ... what is your `submitForm` JS function doing and do you even need it?

Comment: I think that `submitForm` JS function is messing up the CSRF token

Comment: can i see what ```submitForm()``` function does ?